# How to use angualrjs for front-end with YII 2.0 framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yii

I am new to learn angularjs and I want to use **angularjs** for front-end with **YII 2.0**.

I googled but did not find any solution, sorry if someone asked the same question.

**Using advanced app YII 2.0** I have added angular.min.js and angular-resource.min.js to rootproject/frontend/assets/AppAsset.php

```
public $js = [
'assets/angularjavascript/angular.min.js',
'assets/angularjavascript/angular-resource.min.js',
];
```

**index.php file**

```
<html  data-ng-app=""> 
<head>

</head> 
<body> 

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

        <table>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
            <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php")
       .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

**Errors:**

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
Error: [$injector:modulerr]     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0AR%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A417%0AOd%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A412%0Aa%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A53%0AOd%2F%3C%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A1%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A46%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A300%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A399%0Aab%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A135%0Auc%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381%0Auc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A179%0AJd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A1%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fangularjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A250%3A429%0AjQuery.Callbacks%2Ffire%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fa462caba%2Fjquery.js%3A3094%3A10%0AjQuery.Callbacks%2Fself.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fa462caba%2Fjquery.js%3A3206%3A7%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fa462caba%2Fjquery.js%3A3412%3A1%0Acompleted%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fyii__project%2Fadvanced%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2Fa462caba%2Fjquery.js%3A3428%3A2%0A
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: You have several errors in your code but this is an extremly generic question.

Comment: You should load angular script in your webpage. Include it in footer or before body close tag <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry If I have asked silly question but as being new to angular js I did not find any answer. Now understanding its functionality.

Actually I was searching how to include locally **angular.js** into YII 2.0 framework and I did it myself and [Vineet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4366287/vineet) is also right.

needed to include a angular.js file or to layout for every page of your site.

**Include it into your head tag in your layout file.**

`<script src="/root/yourjs_folder/angular.min.js"></script>`

**This can help someone who may face same problem.**

Thanks again.